# How to use font "Code 128" in RDLC

Tags: c#, fonts, rdlc, barcode, barcode-printing

I have a string that is passed to RDLC report as parameter. How can I make the RDLC report display it as barcode, using the Code 128 code.

Comment: What font family are you using for the 128 barcode?

Comment: You need to have the barcode font installed, there is not one by default.  There are free ones out there, but more often you need to purchase them.  Once you have the font, just select that for the control you want as barcoded.

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1:** For the Basic of RDLS report follow this link:

Create RDLC report

**Step 2:**  Download the bar code font 3 of 9 from this site:

[Barcode Font](https://www.1001fonts.com/barcode-fonts.html)

**Step 3:**  Then go to your rdlc report page:

**Step 4:** Right click on the Textbox you want the barcode to appear and select "TextBox Properties"

**Step 5:** In the Text Box Properties dialog that opens, choose Font and select the barcode font type, then click ok

**Step 6:** Then right click on the TextBox again which you want to make barcode and select-'Expression'

**Step 7:** Append '*' to the expression value and click OK, e.g **barcode-text**.

**Step 8:** Run your application and you can see your barcode in your report like this.

Goto https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/how-to-use-barcode-in-rdlc-based-report1 for more information